# glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 0, 0) still renders?

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer

I have problems utilizing the stencil buffer, and it's seems to boil down to not work at all.
Given the following code:

```
  glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  glClearStencil(0);
  glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glStencilFuncSeparate(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_NEVER, 0, 0);
  glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_INCR, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  { draw something }
  glEnd();
```

The triangles are still drawn!? Am I missing something trivial here?

*Note:
I'm not rendering to a frame buffer, I'm using glStencil...Separate just to make sure it's not related to front\back, I've kept bits of code that to me doesn't seem related.*

Comment: "*I'm not rendering to a frame buffer*" Then what are you rendering to?

Comment: What I mean is, I am rendering directly to the screen, ie no framebuffer objects are activated.

Comment: Where are you clearing the other buffers?

Comment: @NicolBolas: They are cleared (updated the code, and retested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a stencil buffer. And by the specification (from 4.3 core, folio page 432):

> If there is no stencil buffer, no stencil modification can occur, and it is as if the
>   stencil tests always pass, regardless of any calls to StencilFunc.

Comment: You mean I have to render to a frame buffer object with a stencil buffer attached?

Comment: @ViktorSehr: No; you have to ensure that whatever framebuffer you use has a stencil buffer. If you're rendering to an FBO, then that means you need to use a packed depth/stencil buffer. If you're rendering to the default framebuffer, then you need to use a pixel format that provides a stencil buffer. That's platform-specific, so unless you mention how you're creating your context, I can't really help. Also note that "framebuffer" is *one word*, not two.

Comment: Seems I didn't provide a stencil buffer to the default-\screen frame(no space)buffer. Thanks!